# What is the difference between System.Data.SQLite.dll and SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm starting to learn sqlite. I have referenced the System.Data.SQLite.dll in my Visual Studio project but I don't understand where SQLite.Interop.dll fits in the picture ? Should I also reference it or include it in my project ?

Thx.

Comment: Personally, when I used the Compact Framework version of System.Data.SQLite on a Windows Mobile device, my app wouldn't launch any SQL requests because the SQLite.Interop.dll were missing. So I think this file is only needed in this case (I tested also with a desktop .NET Framework application, this file was not needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only reference System.Data.SQLite.dll.

The interop dll is "internal plumbing" for SQLite.  it needs to be where System.Data.SQLite.dll can load it.